# Ns3 : insertion sort code fragment terminated with signal SIGSEGV error

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, ns-3

The following code fragment is causing the error

> "terminated with signal SIGSEGV " in NS3

The code is for insertion sort.
All variables are **uint16_t** type
Following are the values of corresponding variables when program control enter this sorting code.

```
selectedCells[10] = {2,4,5} 
rate[10] = {5,2,0} //[Sorting of only this array has to be done]
indexVal = 3
```

Code Fragment

```
for( j = 1; j < indexVal; j++)
{
    tempCell = selectedCells[j];
    tempRate = rate[j];
    for( k = j-1;k >= 0 && tempRate < rate[k]; k-- ){
        rate[k+1] = rate[k];
        selectedCells[k+1] = selectedCells[k];    
    }
    rate[k+1] = tempRate;
    selectedCells[k+1] = tempCell;
}// Sorting algorithm
```

Please help. When control gets into inner for loop 1 iteration is occurred and terminating with above mentioned error.

Comment: are the loop variables signed or unsigned?

Comment: unsigned. all variables are uint16_t  type

Comment: `for( k = j-1;k >= 0 && tempRate < rate[k]; k-- ){`: uint16_t k will underflow to UINT16_MAX and will always be >=0 . `rate[UINT16_MAX]` will cause segmentation violation. Please have unittests and a debugger ready.